# LinkedIn-SignIn API (get_profile() not working)

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, linkedin-api, google-signin, basic-authentication

This is my code and I'm getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'HTTPError' object has no attribute 'message'

```
def profile_details(result):
    token = result.access_token
    exp_time = result.expires_in
    application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(token=token)
    member_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/zzzzz'
    email = 'xxxxx@gmail.com'
    profile = application.get_profile(member_email= email)
    profile_1 = application.get_profile()
    print(profile)
    print(profile_1)
```

I tried providing my LinkedIn URL as well as e-mail,both are not working and showing the same error. I need to fetch the profile details with or without providing the user credentials.